# Add a condition with 2 contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, velo

I have this little code that expand a table if the user enter the correct password from the database.

I would like to add a condition that he must enter his mail and is password. It would be contains mail AND contains password.

Someone help me please ?

```js
import wixData from 'wix-data';
//For full API documentation, including code examples visit      http://wix.to/94BuAAs

$w.onReady(function() {
  //TODO: import wixData from 'wix-data';

  $w("#table1").collapse();
});

export function searchButton_onClick(event) {
  $w("#table1").expand();
  wixData.query('Mipropriedad')
    .contains('contrasena', $w('#input2').value)
    .find()
    .then(res => {
      $w('#table1').rows = res.items;
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This does not appear to be the complete code. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, have you looked at https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-users.html#promptLogin ?

Comment: yes, but its for the member of six site. The only thing I want if that the visitor enters his mail and password, then a table appears with his database elements. the url is https://www.bgahouseservices.com/mi-casa . Also the code search in the database the password but it doesn't respect the lower and upper case.

Answer (score 0):

If the email address is stored in the same collection as the password, all you need to do is add another filter to the query. (I also changed your `contains` to an `eq`.)

```
wixData.query('Mipropriedad')
  .eq('contrasena', $w('#input2').value)
  .eq('emailFieldNameHere'), $w('#emailInputElementIDHere').value)
  .find()
  .then(res => {
    $w('#table1').rows = res.items;
  });
```